# Data-structure to repeatably find the first `n` bits in a large bitset

Tags: data-structures

I'm trying to find a data-structure to do the following in a very efficient
manner:

I have a bit-vector (implicit or physical) that represent the currently used
resources. At any point in time, I want to be able to find the *first* `n`
available bits and return their starting point and the number of allocated bits
(and zero out the bits in the bit-vector). Additionally, I also want to be able
to return these bits in-between allocations (i.e., resetting them to 1), in a
possibly out-of-order fashion.

Is there some data-structure out there optimized for such a use-case?

So far I've considered a few simpler approaches, such as:

- Tracking the first available bit and search forwards.
- Maintaining a list of the first-available regions, possibly ordered into a
  RB-tree based on the number of available bits and position in the vector.

However, these approaches all seem to have quite a few draw-backs. The first is
very search intensive, (although, it is *very* cache coherent). The second
approach is very memory intensive (e.g., representing a bitset of `010101...`
would use *alot* of memory), and requires somewhat extra coalescing algorithms
to work correctly.

## Examples

After a number of allocations/deallocations, we have the bitset:
`011000111011111111`. The following operations could occur on it:

- Requesting an allocation of `n = 1` would return `{index=1, length=1}`. Bitset
  becomes: `001000111011111111`.
- Requesting an allocation of `n = 2` would return `{index=1, length=2}`. Bitset
  becomes `000000111011111111`.
- Requesting an allocation of `n = 3` would return `{index=6, length=3}`. Bitset
  becomes `011000000011111111`.
- Requesting an allocation of `n = 4` would return `{index=10, length=4}`. Bitset becomes `011000111000001111`.
- Deallocation of `{index=0, length=1}`. Bitset becomes `011000111011111111`.
- Deallocation of `{index=4, length=3}`. Bitset becomes `011111111011111111`.

Note that these are individual examples. They do not happen in order. They are
also trivial examples: A practical bitset would actually contain millions if not
billions of entries.

Comment: What would be the result of a retrieval? An array of  bit-indices?

Comment: The retrieval would result in an index to the first used resource. The resources in this scenario cannot be moved, just marked as in use. I.e., it would return a struct with the index to the bit and the number of allocated bits (and zero them out in the bitset)

Comment: Could you edit your question and give concrete examples?

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: Please check the title: `repeatably` or *repeat**ed**ly*?

Comment: It's *repeatably*: I want to be able to find the first available n bits again and again. (https://thecontentauthority.com/blog/repeatedly-vs-repeatably)